# Delete duplicates and sort a list of sets separately?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, sets, subset

I have a set where it has three subsets. I want to have each element of each subsets appears only once, sorted, but the order of subsets does not change. For example: I want to get from
$$
\{\{5,2,2,3\},\{1,2,1,6\},\{7,4,5,2\}\}
$$
the following
$$
\{\{2,3,5\},\{1,2,6\},\{2,4,5,7\}\}
$$
I did this in three times using

> Union[{5,2,2,3}]
>
> Union[{1,2,1,6}]
>
> Union[{7,4,5,2}]

, but I guess there must be a shortcut.

Thanks.

Comment: Union /@ {{5, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 1, 6}, {7, 4, 5, 2}}?

Comment: Please read [guide/ListManipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html). It is a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), we have

```
list = {{5, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 1, 6}, {7, 4, 5, 2}}
Sort /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ list
```

Equivalently,

```
Union/@list
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using the reverse one  "Map[Union[list]]"    :p